# Iterate through IF-MIB::ifDescr?

Tags: networking, cisco, switch, snmp

I am using snmpget in order to get the description of a specific switch port.  How could I read each not null value?  I.E. do a "for-each" sort of operation on the set of IF-MIB::ifDescr values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `snmpwalk` command for this, this goes over all items below the one you specify in the MIB tree.

I don't have anything to query, but you could read each line and filter on the text with something sort of like the following in the shell:

```
while read line; do
   if $(echo $line | grep NULL); then
      echo $line
   fi
done < <(snmpwalk -Os -c public -v 1 zeus system)
```